# Can shaders created in Blender Shader Editor be exported as OpenGL shaders in versions of Blender 2.9x?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, eevee-render-engine, opengl, shader-nodes

I have created a shader in the Blender Shader Editor, since I find it very powerful and easy to use. I would like to export this shader so I can use it outside Blender. Is this possible for versions of Blender 2.9x?

Thank you!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you very much!